# IN clause using JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, in-clause

I have JavaScript code in my app that checks values using the OR(||) condition as in code snippet below. The number of OR conditions is not small in most of my code.

**Question**: Is there a way to make the code that has many multiple OR conditions more concise by using something like this:`value IN ('s','b','g','p','z')`? I was interested in something that comes as close as possible to an IN clause.

```
if(value === "s" || value === "b" || value === "g" || value === "p" || value === "z") {

  //do something

 }
```

Comment: Put the values in an array and use `.indexOf()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [array.contains(obj) in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not lodash's [`includes`](https://lodash.com/docs#includes) function?

```
var val = 's';
var criterion = ['s','b','g','p','z'];
_.includes(criterion, val);
```

returns `true`;

Comment: How would this be applied to the code snippet I have?

Comment: Can I pass a variable as first parameter to _includes? var v = "'s','b','g','p','z'". Just saw your edit when I posted this. So it seems like a nice library.

Comment: Or just use `criterion.includes(val)` as now included with ES7 or by the question `if( ['s','b','g','p','z'].includes(value) )`

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way is to create an array of valid values, then make sure your value is in that list. You can use the [`indexOf` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for that:

```
var allowed = ['s', 'b', 'g', 'p', 'z'];
if (allowed.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
  // do something
}
```

The ES6 standard introduces Sets, which has [a `has` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) to do a similar thing on unique values.

This will work for strings, numbers, and other simple non-object values. Comparing objects with `===` will only succeed if the array/set already contains the exact same object.

Comment: Does indexOf use strict comparision as in ====?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
var values = ['s','b','g','p','z'];

if (values.indexOf(value) > -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use javascript [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) helper.

> The `includes()` method determines whether an array includes a certain
>   element, returning `true` or `false` as appropriate.

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(array1.includes(2));
// expected output: true

var pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'bat'];

console.log(pets.includes('cat'));
// expected output: true

console.log(pets.includes('at'));
// expected output: false
```

Answer (score 1):

There is, in fact, an `in` in JavaScript and it can be used for your case exactly.  Construct a dictionary with any values you like, but using your allowed letters as the keys:

```
allowed = { 's':true, 'b':true, 'g':true, 'p':true, 'z':true };
```

Now you can use the `in` test directly (and more efficiently than a lookup in a list).  Here copied from my JavaScript console:

```
's' in allowed
true

'q' in allowed
false
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution for single characters:

```js
var value = 'g';

if (~'sbgpz'.indexOf(value)) {
    document.write(value + ' found');
}
```

A solution for strings characters:

```js
var value = 'go';

if (~['so', 'bo', 'go', 'po', 'zo'].indexOf(value)) {
    document.write(value + ' found');
}
```

A solution for object properties:

```js
var value = 'go';
var toDo = {
    so: function () { document.write('prop so found'); },
    go: function () { document.write('prop go found'); }
};

value in toDo && toDo[value]();
```